# Specifing type of ES6 destructured parameters in Flow

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint, flowtype, destructuring

In ES6, you can use named parameters, e.g.

```
// @flow
const makeRequest = (dateFrom: Object, dateTo: Object, subdomain: string, {shortId, label} = {}) => {
  let request = {}
  try {
    dateValidation(dateFrom, dateTo)
    subdomainValidation(subdomain)

    request.subdomain = subdomain
    request.dateFrom = dateFrom.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    request.dateTo = dateTo.format('YYYY-MM-DD')

    if (shortId) {
      request.shortId = shortId
    }
    if (label) {
      request.label = label
    }
  } catch (error) {
    throw error
  }
  return request
}
```

ref: http://www.2ality.com/2011/11/keyword-parameters.html

it is a part of my code, and as you can see I used `{shortId, label} = {}` as an parameter, which means i want parameters named `shortId`, `label`, but it is optional!('cause initialized by {})

The point is, I want to use Flow as a static type checker, like I did in `dateFrom: Object`. But if I do this `{shortId, label}: Object = {}`, ESLint says `Parsing Error: binding rvalue`.

So, how can I use Flow, ES6 named parameters at once?

Comment: *"In ES6, you can use named parameters"* - JS has *always* supported named function parameters. You're asking about *default* parameter values.

Comment: OP is referring to named parameters via destructuring, which is a new feature http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_parameter-handling.html

Comment: I don't think you need to specify the data type when you're using a default parameter. The type is the type of the default value. [You can see an example in the docs here](https://flowtype.org/docs/functions.html#variadics)

Comment: There's an open issue for this: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/183. I guess the best solution for now is to make eslint happy and silence flowtype...